# Inject file into Helm template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a list of properties defined in `values.yaml` as follows:

```
files:
 - "file1"
 - "file2"
```

Then in my template I want to create config maps out of my values.

I came up with the following template:

```
{{- range $value := .Values.files }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata: 
    name: {{ $value }}
data:
    {{ $value }}: {{ .Files.Get (printf "%s/%s" "files" $value) | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
```

As you can see I want to have configmaps with same name as files. I mixed up several parts of documentation, however my template does not work as expected.

How can I achieve configmap creation through templates?

**//EDIT**
I expect to have the following ConfigMap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata: 
    name: file1
data:
    file1: <file1 content>
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata: 
    name: file2
data:
    file2: <file2 content>
```

Comment: *does not work as expected* means ... it rebooted your computer? it drank all your beer? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63581972/edit) and say what did happen and what you expected to happen instead

Comment: @mdaniel edited, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
{{- $files := .Files }}
{{- range $value := .Values.files }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata: 
  name: {{ $value }}
  data:
    {{ $value }}: |
{{ $files.Get (printf "%s/%s" "files" $value) | indent 6 }}
{{- end }}
```

You problem seems to be with incorrect indentation. Make sure the line with `$files.Get` starts with no spaces.

And I also added `{{- $files := .Files }}` to access `.Files`, because for some reason `range` is changeing the `.` scope.

I have found [this example](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/#basic-example) in documentation but it seems to work only if file's content are one-line. So if your files are one line only, then you should check the example.

Also notice the `|` after `{{ $value }}:`. You need it because file content is a multiline string. Check [this StackQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/how-do-i-break-a-string-over-multiple-lines) on how to use multiline strings in yaml.

Comment: Works as I wanted, thanks! Additonal question: is there a way to get FIles without the need to define them in `values.yaml`? I've seen there is a `.Files.Glob` wich may be useful.

Comment: Yes you can do it with `.Files.Glob`. If you have troubles with using it, preferably create a new question for it to be compliant with stackOverflow guidlines.

Answer (score 0):

Try something as below

```
{{ $currentScope := .}}
{{- range $value := .Values.files }}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
    name: {{ $value }}
data:
    {{- with $currentScope}}
        {{ $value }}: {{ .Files.Get (printf "%s/%s" "files" $value) | indent 4 }}
    {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

My Chart structure

```
├── Chart.yaml
├── charts
├── files
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2
├── templates
│   ├── configmap.yaml
│   ├── deployment.yaml
│   ├── secret.yaml
│   └── service.yaml
└── values.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

It's now possible to use [Files.Glob](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/) to render the contents of files into ConfigMaps and Secrets using `AsConfig` and `AsSecret` respectively

e.g.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: MyConifg
data:
{{ (.Files.Glob "files/*").AsConfig | indent 2 }}
```

In this simple case, you'll end up with 1 ConfigMap which contains an entry for each file, properly escaped and formatted, but it can easily be adapted with a `range` block to create multiple ConfigMaps